access public ip of openvpn server via tun0 device
My OpenVPN works well with only one issue...

I run OpenVPN on Synology router (SRM system) with public IP and hostname.
I have OpenVPN on 172.22.0.0/24. I allowed 172.22.0.0/24 to access the router in router FW with the port I want to access. I also allowed ICMP for 172.22.0.0/24 for debugging purposes.
I allowed UDP/1194 for OpenVPN to the Internet on the FW.
No other FW rules.
I use 'redirect-gateway def1' in the OpenVPN client conf.
I use Gnome/NetworkManager (the issue is still present using openvpn command or openvpn3 command)

I can not access the public IP/hostname via the tun0 device from either of my Arch Linux PCs. However, by connecting to OpenVPN on Android devices via a cellular network - I can access the public IP using both of my two Android devices. No issue here. - Since that, I think the server side is set correctly and I would like to ask for help setting up the Linux PC.
My route tabe on one the PCs looks like this:
default via 172.22.0.5 dev tun0 proto static metric 50 
default via <client gw> dev enp5s0 proto dhcp src <client ip> metric 100 
<openvpn public IP> via <client gw> dev enp5s0 proto static metric 50 
<client ip>/25 dev enp5s0 proto kernel scope link src <client ip> metric 100 
<client gw> dev enp5s0 proto static scope link metric 50 
172.22.0.0/24 via 172.22.0.5 dev tun0 proto static metric 50 
172.22.0.1 via 172.22.0.5 dev tun0 proto static metric 50 
172.22.0.5 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 172.22.0.6 metric 50 
192.168.1.0/24 via 172.22.0.5 dev tun0 proto static metric 50 

I understand the rule:
<openvpn public IP> via <client gw> dev enp5s0 proto static metric 50 is wrong but even if I set:
ip route add <openvpn public IP> via 172.22.0.5 dev tun0 proto static metric 40

It does not work. I tried disabling auto-routing and setting routing manually but no luck.
I want this use-case because closing vaultwarden behind OpenVPN. It also works on my Android phone so it must be possible. Could somebody help, please?
UPDATED:
I lernt some stuff and I can make it possible now. However, I am not very happy with the solution.
My solution:
Filter the OpenVPN udp traffic to enp5s0 and other tcp traffic send via tun0.
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p udp  -d <openvpn public IP>  -j MARK --set-mark 0x20
ip rule add from all fwmark 0x20 lookup other
ip route add default via <client gw> dev enp5s0 table other 
ip route add <openvpn public IP> via 172.22.0.5 dev tun0 metric 10
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p udp -d <openvpn public IP> -j MASQUERADE

The problem is that I still can not access the public IP but the relevant traffic goes via tun0 now. I added rules like:
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d <openvpn public IP> --dport <service1-port> -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.1
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d <openvpn public IP> --dport <service2-port> -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.132:<service2-port-reverseproxy>

This works. I hope for a solution without DNATing the public IP. Could somebody help, please?
